# How do I transfer my cassandra data to pyspark using QueryCassandra and ExecutePySpark Nifi Processors?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, apache-nifi, kylo

I'm just querying cassandra table using querycassandra processor but what I'm not understanding is how do I pass my Json output file into ExecutePyspark processor as a Input file and later on I need to pass my Spark output data to Hive. Please help me on this, Thanks.

My Query Cassandra Properties:

[image]

Pyspark Properties:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this flow that uses 4 processors as below:

[QueryCassandra](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-cassandra-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.cassandra.QueryCassandra/index.html) -> [UpdateAttribute](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-update-attribute-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute/additionalDetails.html) -> [PutFile](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutFile/index.html) -> [ExecutePySpark](https://github.com/Teradata/kylo/blob/master/integrations/nifi/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-spark-bundle/nifi-spark-processors/src/main/java/com/thinkbiganalytics/nifi/pyspark/core/ExecutePySpark.java)

**Step 1**: `QueryCassandra` processor: Execute a CQL on Cassandra and output the result in a flow file.

**Step 2**: `UpdateAttribute` processor: Assign the property `filename` a value containing name for a temporary file on disk that will contain the query results. Use [NiFi expression language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html) for generating the file name so that it will be different for each run. Create a property `result_directory` and assign a value for a folder on disk that NiFi has write permissions to.

- property: `filename`
- value: `cassandra_result_${now():toNumber()}`
- property: `result_directory`
- value: `/tmp`

[image]

**Step 3**: `PutFile` processor: Configure the `Directory` property with the value `${result_directory}` populated in Step 2.

[image]

**Step 4**: `ExecutePySpark` processor: Pass the filename with its location as an argument to the PySpark application via the `PySpark App Args` processor property. The application can then have code to read data from the file on disk, process it and write to Hive.

- property: `PySpark App Args`
- value: `${result_directory}/${filename}`

[image]

Additionally, you could configure more attributes in Step 2 (UpdateAttribute) that could be then passed as arguments in Step 4 (ExecutePySpark) and considered by the PySpark application in writing to Hive (for example, the Hive database and table name).

Comment: Thank you so much Jagrut it's working and able to write data to hive through my spark apllication but my spark application only needs to perform only transformations there and need separate processor to write data into Hive. Is there any mechanisam in spark to genarate a flow file and pass it to the next processor ?

Comment: @KarthikMannava You might try the ExecuteStream processor so you can read from stdin and write to stdout in your Python script. I don't think there's any built-in support in Spark to write directly to a NiFi FlowFile though.

Comment: @GregHart How do I call my flow file content in my spark application using execute stream command processor? When I'm trying directly with python read stdin flow files are stucking in queue between queryCassandra and ExecuteStreamCommand Processors.

Comment: @KarthikMannava You would read from stdin and write to stdout. If that's not working you should create a new question showing your Python code.